# finding number between 2 parenthesis using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

In a line I may have `(123,456)`
I want to find it using pattern in java. What I did is:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(");
while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
      System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
}
```

Input: `This is test (123,456)`
Output:`Start index: 0 End index: 1 (`
Why??

Comment: Thanks now the problem changes. Please see the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how `\W` is going to match it. `\W` matches a non word character.

You will also have to escape those backslashes.

Round brackets need to be escaped , as by default they are used for grouping.

Maybe the regex you meant was

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\([,\\d]+\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String matched = matcher.group();
    //Do something with it  
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
\\(     # Match (
[,\\d]+ # Match 1+ digits/commas. Don't be surprised if it matches (,,,,,,)
\\)     # Match )
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it in one line:

```
String num = str.replaceAll(".*\\(([\\d,]+)\\).*", "$1");
```

Comment: Before **Edit** :
You missed a round bracket. This is going to be terribly inefficient. .* in front of an regex is a killer.

Comment: @bsd thx 4 the bracket. Re efficiency, who cares? This is "efficient" for the programmer, which is more valuable and important than efficiency for the CPU (programmers cost a lot more than computers). If after supportive evidence was found that this code was a significant performance bottleneck, *then* you would add more code or change the regex etc to make it harder to code but easier for the JVM to execute. But doing the "hard way" first would be "optimizing early", which is one of the worst anti-patterns to fall into. The execution time of this code would be fast enough for production use.